# Django UserProfile matching query does not exist

Tags: django

I'm making an forum using this tutorial http://lightbird.net/dbe/forum2.html and I encountered an error .

When I click edit profile , it suppose to point to this page instead I get an error(below)

[image]

```
 DoesNotExist at /forum/profile/1/

 UserProfile matching query does not exist.

 Request Method:    GET
 Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8000/forum/profile/1/
 Django Version:    1.4.3
 Exception Type:    DoesNotExist
 Exception Value:   

 UserProfile matching query does not exist.

 Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

 C:\djcode\mysite\forum\views.py in profile

         profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=pk)
```

I think this error mean , django can't receive my admin login .

This is part of my fbase.html

```
  <a href="{% url ben:profile user.pk %}">Edit profile</a>
```

which point to my URLconf.

```
  from django.conf.urls import patterns,include,url
  from django.contrib import admin
  from django.conf import settings

  urlpatterns = patterns('forum.views',
                   url(r'^$','main',name='main'),
                   url(r"^forum/(\d+)/$", "forum",name ="forum"),
                   url(r"^thread/(\d+)/$","thread",name = "thread"),
                   url(r"^post/(new_thread|reply)/(\d+)/$", "post",name = "post"),
                   url(r"^reply/(\d+)/$", "reply" , name ="reply"),
                   url(r"^new_thread/(\d+)/$", "new_thread" , name  ="new_thread"),
                   url(r"^profile/(\d+)/$", "profile",name= "profile"),
  )
```

and into my view function

```
  def profile(request, pk):
      """Edit user profile."""
      profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=pk)
      img = None

      if request.method == "POST":
          pf = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=profile)
          if pf.is_valid():
              pf.save()
              # resize and save image under same filename
              imfn = pjoin(MEDIA_ROOT, profile.avatar.name)
              im = PImage.open(imfn)
              im.thumbnail((160,160), PImage.ANTIALIAS)
              im.save(imfn, "JPEG")
      else:
          pf = ProfileForm(instance=profile)

      if profile.avatar:
          img = "/media/" + profile.avatar.name
      return render_to_response("forum/profile.html", add_csrf(request, pf=pf, img=img))
```

This is my models.py

```
  from django.db import models
  from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  from django.contrib import admin
  from string import join
  from mysite.settings import MEDIA_ROOT

  class Forum(models.Model):
      title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
      def __unicode__(self):
          return self.title
      def num_posts(self):
          return sum([t.num_posts() for t in self.thread_set.all()])

      def last_post(self):
          if self.thread_set.count():
              last = None
              for t in self.thread_set.all():
                  l = t.last_post()
                  if l:
                      if not last: last = l
                      elif l.created > last.created: last = l
              return last
  class Thread(models.Model):
      title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
      created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
      creator = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
      forum = models.ForeignKey(Forum)

      def __unicode__(self):
          return unicode(self.creator) + " - " + self.title
      def num_posts(self):
          return self.post_set.count()

      def num_replies(self):
          return self.post_set.count() - 1

      def last_post(self):
          if self.post_set.count():
              return self.post_set.order_by("created")[0]
  class Post(models.Model):
      title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
      created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
      creator = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
      thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread)
      body = models.TextField(max_length=10000)

      def __unicode__(self):
          return u"%s - %s - %s" % (self.creator, self.thread, self.title)

      def short(self):
          return u"%s - %s\n%s" % (self.creator, self.title, self.created.strftime("%b %d, %I:%M %p"))
short.allow_tags = True

  ### Admin

  class ForumAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      pass

  class ThreadAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      list_display = ["title", "forum", "creator", "created"]
      list_filter = ["forum", "creator"]

  class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      search_fields = ["title", "creator"]
      list_display = ["title", "thread", "creator", "created"]
  class UserProfile(models.Model):
      avatar = models.ImageField("Profile Pic", upload_to="images/", blank=True, null=True)
      posts = models.IntegerField(default=0)
      user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)

      def __unicode__(self):
          return unicode(self.user)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to put pk in your render:

```
return render_to_response("forum/profile.html", add_csrf(request, pf=pf, 'profile': profile, img=img))
```

In html:

```
<a href="{% url ben:profile profile.id %}">Edit profile</a>
```

Comment: ("keyword can't be an expression", ('C:\\djcode\\mysite\\forum\\views.py', 56, None, 'return render_to_response("forum/profile.html", add_csrf(request, pf=pf, img=img ,\'pk\'=pk))\n')) I got this error cathy

Comment: Ok I updated my answer, I change it to profile. One more thing, if the output is none. User must be authenticate to get id

Comment: ("keyword can't be an expression", ('C:\\djcode\\mysite\\forum\\views.py', 56, None, 'return render_to_response("forum/profile.html", add_csrf(request, \'profile\'=profile, img=img ,pk=pk))\n'))